# Community Poll: Are your family/friends knowing about your participation in this site?

Tags: discussion, community

When anyone searches any info about Hinduism (philosophy, *itihasa, smritis*), then most likely this site may pop-up due to good indexing.
If your friends, relatives search something on Hinduism, then it's likely that your post may pop-up!

Most of the community members here keep their profiles secret by choosing a different username and not keeping the self's image. Hence no one will know that it's 'you' who posted that question/answer.

Have you ever shared your profile info with any of your friends/relatives, or have you chosen to be a masked vigilante like Batman? :-)

---

This is a light hearted question and no one is expected to share their profile info here. The answer can be like:

- If you haven't informed about your participation, then when do you intend to inform it?
- If you informed, then how was their reaction?
- Were you able to bring a new member to this community by impressing with your contribution?
- Any interesting personal experience on this particular topic ...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Some of my friends and family members know that I participate on our site and also on Stack Exchange Network. I shown some questions and answers to them and also shared some questions and answers through social media.

They read some of my answers and reaction was neutral. They were like [Okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgN3H.gif).

Yes, I shared some of my questions and answers to friends. Some of them shown interest to join the site and post some questions they come across in daily life about beliefs and practices. But unfortunately, some of them were duplicates and some had a chance for closure. So, they haven't posted. Besides these, I was successful in bringing a use r to the site. One of my family members have contributed to the site (through edits and answers). We should share our helpful posts to our friends and family and they can also join the site. There is nothing wrong in that. User base is important for a successful beta site and more contributing users can help us for graduation.

I had a personal experience regarding this. At a point of time, when I spent more time on site i.e more than 4 hours a day (which is equivalent to spending time on Social media platforms), my family warned me to reduce time on the site and spend it on real life like any other caring family. So, I followed that.

Comment: *my family warned me to reduce time on the site and spend it on real life* ... the same happened with me, but then I decided to reduce the family time and increase the on site time ... :|